# Sign Firefox extension without publishing on AMO

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, web-ext

I have a Firefox extension that was published on AMO. Recently, Mozilla unlisted it because it did not met some of their guidelines (paid software required to use it). They suggested me to self-host the extension for distribution.

So, for this I found `web-ext` tool from their documentation for signing the extension before distributing it. However, when I execute the command `web-ext sign`, it generates a signed `.xpi` file which is okay, but it also published the extension again on AMO. Quoting from their [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Distribution#Signing_your_add-ons):

So, is there a way to only generate the signed file and not publish it pn AMO, because I am afraid they'll take it down again for the same reason and I don't want to do this for each update.

> Using the signing API or web-ext returns you signed add-ons, with no distribution listing created on AMO.

Answer (score 2):

The entry that is created on AMO when using `web-ext sign` is not listed. This means you achieved what you wanted to do: obtain a signed version of your addon without listing it on AMO.

The minimal entry that is created on AMO is needed for technical reasons. It doesn't show AMO users any version of your addon.

Comment: If I go to the link that the tool provides, I can install the extension. So I am pretty sure, users can see it and install it.

Comment: Only *you* can see it when logged into AMO.  Log out and the URL will resolve to a 404 message.